# Python: how to groupby a dataframe with column name numbered for the unique values of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following where I have different number of `case` and 3 unique values for `val`.

```
df
     case    val
0     0       x
1     0       y 
2     0       z
3     1       x 
4     1       z
5     2       y
```

Now I would like to have a dataframe with a single row for each case and numbered columns for `val`. I would like something like this:

```
df1
      case     val0    val1    val2
0       0        x       y      z
1       1        x      nan     z
2       2       nan      y     nan
```

Comment: For a given case, how to you determine among all the val values which ones will be val0, val1, etc. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot(index='case', columns='val', values='val')
out.columns = [f'val{i}' for i in range(len(out.columns))]
```

```
>>> out
     val0 val1 val2
case               
0       x    y    z
1       x  NaN    z
2     NaN    y  NaN
```

Comment: is it possible to rename the columns with the pivot command?

Comment: @emax. I updated my answer unfortunately, I can't do it in one line after or before pivot.